# do i need to set table to utf with database?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I want to set the character coding of my tables to UTF-8. So what I am planning is set the database to UTF-8 instead of tables.

My question is, if I set UTF-8 to database, default all tables under that database also get to utf-8?

Comment: ... unless the CREATE TABLE code says something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default collation is exactly that, just a default, so when you create a table that does not have collation info that table will use the default value. In particular, there're two things that setting a database default will *not* accomplish:

- Change the encoding of existing tables
- Force new tables to use such encoding